# Can't convert string into double using DoubleParse

Tags: java

I'm having NumberFormatException when i'm trying to convert a string into double. It seems that i've got the right way to do it but the exception still showing up. It's really driven me mad as i've been trying over last week. Here is what i'm trying to do:

```
String csvFile="N:/Downloads/Chrome Downloads/GeoIPCountryWhois.csv";
BufferedReader br=null;
String line="";
String cvspl=",";
    try{
        for(int i=0;i<5000;i++)
        {
        //System.out.println("I'm here in retriving IP");
        br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        while ((line=br.readLine())!=null){
            String[] country=line.split(cvspl);
            l.add(country[0]);
            double a = Double.parseDouble(country[2]);
            double b = Double.parseDouble(country[3]);
            IpParameters p = new IpParameters(a, b);
            IP.put(country[0], p);

        }           
        }


    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){

        e.printStackTrace();

    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        if (br !=null){
            try{
                br.close();
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

}
}

I'm successfully retrieving the numbers from the file. When i print out country[2], it shows the value which is stored in this index.

Comment: try with `Double.parseDouble(country[2].trim())`.

Comment: Can you show us the value you're trying to parse, and perhaps the line in the file? Jorn may very well be right - if there's white space the exception would be thrown.

Comment: Offtopic: I suggest using the try-with-resource syntax.

Comment: If you just show code error it was be easy to answer. :|

Comment: NumberFormatException means string is not a double and can't be parsed. Please use debug or logging to get an exact value at country[2] and country[3], then you (or we) can understand what's going on

Comment: You're opening the `Reader` 5000 times for some reason, in addition to unnecessarily initializing it to `null`, then closing it only after the 5000th open. It's not shown what types `l` (an exceptionally inadvisable variable name) and `IP` (a convention-violating variable name) point to. It would also help if you'd publish complete information to help us diagnose your issue, such as the actual contents of the error message, and a complete code example.

Answer (score 2):

I find this file https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alecthomas/geoip/master/GeoIPCountryWhois.csv 
 (if it's similar to your working file) and test it with These two lines from it:

```
"1.0.0.0","1.0.0.255","16777216","16777471","AU","Australia"
"1.0.1.0","1.0.3.255","16777472","16778239","CN","China"
```

and error was

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""16777216""
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
    at Test.main(Test.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

my code that works:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;

/**
 * Created by mojtab23 on 8/1/16.
 */
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";
        String cvspl = ",";
        try {

            //System.out.println("I'm here in retriving IP");
            br = new BufferedReader(new StringReader("\"1.0.0.0\",\"1.0.0.255\",\"16777216\",\"16777471\",\"AU\",\"Australia\"\n" +
                    "\"1.0.1.0\",\"1.0.3.255\",\"16777472\",\"16778239\",\"CN\",\"China\""));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] country = line.split(cvspl);
//                    l.add(country[0]);
                double a = Double.parseDouble(country[2].replaceAll("\"", ""));
                double b = Double.parseDouble(country[3].replaceAll("\"", ""));
//                    IpParameters p = new IpParameters(a, b);
                System.out.println("IP: " + country[0]);
                System.out.println(a + " ," + b);


            }


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```